# 2005 chrysler 300c 5.7 hemi vibration after 70km/hr

Tags: engine, vibration, chrysler, rear-differential, chrysler-300c

I have my chrysler and it vibrates everytime I press on the petal but only after 70km an hour! If I let go of the pedal it doesn't vibrate. When I press on the pedal it does. Only after 70km/hr. No misfire or check engine light. Not sure if it's time to service the differential or maybe something worse. Love the car and don't want to get rid of it.it's a rwd

Answer (score -1):

I also have this issue.  I'll try and post the results when I'm done working on it.   Parts are being delivered  few days.   I think I have it figured.  Flex joints are cracked up.  Driveshaft center support bearing have chatter in it and some outer CV joint side to side movvement with noise so I'm replacing them all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).